# Solving the riemann sum of a trig function

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

[image]

I know the function $f$ in this case will be $cos\frac{4k\pi}{5n}$. I'm quite sure how to compute the function. I tried U substitution but it's kind of messy, is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: But what is $f(t)$? $\cos(4k\pi/5n)$ doesn't depend on $t$.

Comment: Would it be $\frac{5n}{4\pi} \int cos(t) dt $?

Comment: Close. I posted an explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressing the integral using a Right-Hand Sum, you have
$$\int_0^{4\pi/5}f(t)dt = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(0+\frac{4k\pi/5}{n}\right)\left(\frac{4\pi/5}{n}\right)= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right)f\left(\frac{4k\pi}{5n}\right). $$
This matches what you're given if 
$$\cos\left(\frac{4k\pi}{5n}\right) = \left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right)f\left(\frac{4k\pi}{5n}\right), $$
i.e., if 
$$f\left(\frac{4k\pi}{5n}\right) = \left(\frac{5}{4\pi}\right)\cos\left(\frac{4k\pi}{5n}\right). $$
So let
$$f\left(t\right) = \left(\frac{5}{4\pi}\right)\cos\left(t\right). $$
From here you can just compute the integral.